# How to query with multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, filter

I'm trying to create a form where a user can search a database using multiple filters. I have two questions: How do I query the database with multiple arrays as each filter will be stored in a variable as an array on the results page. The second is: How do I make sure that if the user leaves a filter blank, the filter does not make it into the query? Also it is not required that the user enter anything into the two first text entries. Thanks.

```html
<form action="results.php" method="post">
   <table id="name-inputs">
    <tr>
     <td>Common Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="commonName" class="text-input" maxlength="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Latin Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="latinName" class="text-input"  maxlength="100"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <div id="plantType-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Plant Type</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="plantType[]" value="Perennial"> Perennial</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="plantType[]" value="Annual"> Annual</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="plantType[]" value="Tree"> Tree</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="plantType[]" value="Shrub"> Shrub</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="plantType[]" value="Herb"> Herb</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="lighting-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Lighting</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="lighting[]" value="Sun"> Sun</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="lighting[]" value="Sun/Part-Sun"> Sun/Part-Sun</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="lighting[]" value="Part-Sun/Shade"> Part-Sun/Shade</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="lighting[]" value="Shade"> Shade</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="water-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Water</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="water[]" value="Average"> Dry</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="water[]" value="Dry/Average"> Dry/Average</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="water[]" value="Average"> Average</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="water[]" value="Wet/Average"> Wet/Average</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="water[]" value="Wet"> Wet</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="foilage-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Foilage</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="foilage[]" value="Decidous"> Decidous</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="foilage[]" value="Evergreen"> Evergreen</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Deer Resistant</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="deer-res[]" value="Yes"> Yes</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="deer-res[]" value="No"> No</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="attracts-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Attracts</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="butter/birds[]" value="Butterflies"> Butterflies</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="butter/birds[]" value="Hummingbirds"> Hummingbirds</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="butter/birds[]" value="Butterflies/Hummingbirds"> Butterflies/Hummingbirds</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="height-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Height</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="height[]" value='1-2"'> 1-2"</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="height[]" value='3-5"'> 3-5"</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="height[]" value='5-10"'> 5-10"</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="height[]" value='10-20"'> 10-20"</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="height[]" value="20'"> 20' +</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="color-container">
    <ul>
     <li class="listing-heading">Flower Color</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="White"> White</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Pink"> Pink</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red"> Red</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue"> Blue</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Orange"> Orange</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Yellow"> Yellow</li>
     <li class="listing"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Purple"> Purple</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="sButton">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

```html
<?php
 $commonName = $_POST['commonName'];
 $latinName = $_POST['latinName'];
 $plantType = $_POST['plantType'];
 $lighting = $_POST['lighting'];
 $water = $_POST['water'];
 $foilage = $_POST['foilage'];
 $attracts = $_POST['attracts'];
 $height = $_POST['height'];
 $color = $_POST['color'];
?>

<?php
  $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Plants");
  if($con->connect_error()) {
   echo "Connection Error: " . $con->connect_error();
  } else {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM plants where plantType like '%$plantType%' AND lighting like '%$lighting%' AND water like '%$water%' AND foilage like '%$foilage%' AND attracts like '%$attracts%' AND height like '%$height%' AND color like '%$color%'";
   $res=$con->query($sql);

   echo "<table id='result-table'>";
   while ($res = $con->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['commonName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['latinName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['plantType'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lighting'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['water'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['foilage'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['attracts'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['color'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you know you should accept answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try my below code.

```
<?php

$commonName = $_POST['commonName'];
$latinName = $_POST['latinName'];

$queryStr = '';
if(isset($_POST['plantType'])){
    $plantType = $_POST['plantType'];
    $queryStr .= " AND plantType like '%$plantType%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['lighting'])){
    $lighting = $_POST['lighting'];
    $queryStr .= " AND lighting like '%$lighting%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['water'])){
    $water = $_POST['water'];
    $queryStr .= " AND water like '%$water%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['foilage'])){
    $foilage = $_POST['foilage'];
    $queryStr .= " AND foilage like '%$foilage%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['attracts'])){
    $attracts = $_POST['attracts'];
    $queryStr .= " AND attracts like '%$attracts%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['height'])){
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $queryStr .= " AND height like '%$height%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['color'])){
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $queryStr .= " AND color like '%$color%'";
}

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Plants");
if($con->connect_error()) {
    echo "Connection Error: " . $con->connect_error();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM plants where 1=1 '$queryStr'";
    $res=$con->query($sql);

    echo "<table id='result-table'>";
    while ($res = $con->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['commonName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['latinName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['plantType'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lighting'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['water'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['foilage'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['attracts'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['color'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

?>

Comment: $_POST['plantType'] and every other entry in $_POST is an array, this will not work.

Comment: Let rstone14 to be specified because If it's array then he/she never used Like in query. I am 100% sure $_POST['plantType'] is not an array.

Comment: No, this IS an array, 'cos if name in a form looks like this - plantType[], it means it has multiple values, this this is an array. And in this case a fragment of $_POST will look like this:
`Array ([0] => Perennial [1] => Tree)`

Comment: In order to use array values in a query in should be transformed in a way like this `function makeSubQuery ($array, $keyword) {
 $subQuery = '';
 if (sizeof($array) > 0) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $subQuery .= " AND $keyword like '%$value' ")
  }
 }
 return $subQuery;
}`

Comment: See my another below answer for Array type. For array, we can use In operator.

Comment: I've tried both versions of code and I can't get anything to pop up. I've even changed just the first name of the plantType input on the form page to just be a single value instead of an array. Example name="plantType[]" into name="plantType", just to see if i can get anything to show up.

Comment: Leave name="plantType[]". I'll try to help you as soon I'll have enough time.

Answer (score 0):

Try my below code

```
<?php

$commonName = $_POST['commonName'];
$latinName = $_POST['latinName'];

$queryStr = '';
if(isset($_POST['plantType'])){
    $plantType = implode("','",$_POST['plantType']);
    $queryStr .= " AND plantType IN ('".$plantType."') ";
}
if(isset($_POST['lighting'])){
    $lighting = implode("','",$_POST['lighting']);
    $queryStr .= " AND lighting IN ('".$lighting."') ";
}

if(isset($_POST['water'])){
    $water = implode("','",$_POST['water']);
    $queryStr .= " AND water IN ('".$water."') ";
}

if(isset($_POST['foilage'])){
    $foilage = implode("','",$_POST['foilage']);
    $queryStr .= " AND foilage IN ('".$foilage."') ";
}

if(isset($_POST['attracts'])){
    $attracts = implode("','",$_POST['attracts']);
    $queryStr .= " AND attracts IN ('".$attracts."') ";
}

if(isset($_POST['height'])){
    $height = implode("','",$_POST['height']);
    $queryStr .= " AND height IN ('".$height."') ";
}

if(isset($_POST['color'])){
    $color = implode("','",$_POST['color']);
    $queryStr .= " AND color IN ('".$color."') ";
}

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Plants");
if($con->connect_error()) {
    echo "Connection Error: " . $con->connect_error();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM plants where 1=1 '$queryStr'";
    $res=$con->query($sql);

    echo "<table id='result-table'>";
    while ($res = $con->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['commonName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['latinName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['plantType'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lighting'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['water'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['foilage'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['attracts'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['color'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}?>
```